# Is this Opto-coupler + MOSFET + Relay schematic correct for my application?

Tags: mosfet, relay, opto-isolator, esp32

I have an ESP32, with a floating voltage supply with 3.3V.

I want to use it's GPIO to turn on/off a solenoid valve that works at 12V and draws a current of about 2A.

I figured that a proper way of doing this is by using a relay, since the load is inductive and I want to be extra careful and protect my MCU, I also want my project to not get too hot. I see that I could use a mosfet for this but I think that those could dissipate more power than a relay would.

I'll be using a very similar circuit to this one but for a Pump that works at 12V with a current draw of about 8 Amps as well. I still haven't looked for the proper components for that one yet.

Please take a look at my circuit and let me know if you guys see something that is off or incorrect, thank you very much in advance.

PS: I considered using Solid State Relays but I find them quite expensive so I discarded them

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Why don't you put your solenoid valve in parallel with D3 and run that circuit directly from 12 volts and lose the relay? Let the MOSFET do the 2 amp switching?

Comment: @Andyaka I feel like using a relay is way safer for my application, I also need my project to stay as cool as possible. 

Do you think that using a MOSFET directly is safe enough for this project? considering the heat problem?

Comment: Check out what the on resistance is for the MOSFET and work out how much power it will produce with a 2 amp load. Then compare that dissipation against the dissipation of a 12 volt relay coil.